# Update nested element on mongodb with condition

Tags: mongodb

With the follow collection structure, how do i update a specific key on a object that is inside a list with a `if` condition?

"Update the key 'price' if the key 'origin' is not 'H' or 'G'"

```
{
    "sku": "x",
    "prices": [
    {
        "id": "0",
        "price": 234.56,
        "origin": "H"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "price": 345.67,
        "origin": "J"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried use `$cond` with `$set` but i got the error: `Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'`, here is a example:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/o1SAirsmRvf

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {sku: 'x', 'prices.id': '1'}},
    {$set: {
        'prices.$.price': {
            $cond: [{
                $or: [
                    {$ne: ['prices.$.origin', 'H']},
                    {$ne: ['prices.$.origin', 'G']},
                ]
            }, 10, 20]
        }
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update using an aggregation pipeline. Thus Mongodb provides a couple of methods to use for updating. Try out the following:

```
db.collection.update(
{$and: [{"sku": "x"}, {"prices.id": 1}, {"prices.origin": {$nin: ["H", "G"]}}]}, 
{$set: {"prices.price": 10}}, {multi:true})
```

Answer (score 0):

may be helpful :

```
db.collection.update(
 {"sku": "x","prices" : { $elemMatch: { origin : {$nin : ['H','G']} } }}},
 {$set: { "prices.$[].price" : 10}})
```